# How to force a resize on Toplevel window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

My adventures with Tkinter continue.
Here is a demo code to try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import threading as thr
import ttk
import Tkinter as tk
import Queue

import loop_file


class MyApp(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.model_queue = Queue.PriorityQueue()
        self.butt = ttk.Button(self, text='Click me!', command=self.proc)
        self.butt.grid()

    def finish_loop_window(self):
        # remove "Wait" message
        self.waitFr.destroy()
        # create Frames for Toplevel window
        graphFr = ttk.Frame(self.loop_win, borderwidth=2, relief='groove')
        graphFr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # update to get the new dimensions
        self.update()
        self.loop_win.update()
        newsize = self.loop_win.winfo_geometry()
        print newsize
        ttk.Label(self.loop_win, text=self.fib_result).grid()
        self.loop_win.geometry(newsize)  # here I expected the window to be resized


    def check_looping_thread_save_results(self):
        """
        Check every 10ms if loop thread is alive.
        """
        if self.loop_thread.is_alive():
            self.after(10, self.check_looping_thread_save_results)
        else:
            self.loop_thread.join()
            # get the results of model processing
            self.fib_result = self.model_queue.get()
            self.finish_loop_window()

    def centrify_widget(self, widget):
        widget.update_idletasks()
        width = widget.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = widget.winfo_screenheight()
        xy = tuple(int(c) for c in widget.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
        xpos = width/2 - xy[0]/2
        ypos = height/2 - xy[1]/2
        widget.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (xy + (xpos, ypos)))

    def proc(self):
        self.model_queue = Queue.PriorityQueue()
        self.loop_thread = thr.Thread(target=loop_file.do_looping,
                                        args=(self.model_queue, ))
        self.loop_thread.start()
        self.after(10, self.check_looping_thread_save_results)

        self.loop_win = tk.Toplevel()
        self.loop_win.title('Toplevel')
        self.waitFr = ttk.Frame(self.loop_win, borderwidth=2, relief='groove')
        self.waitFr.grid(sticky='nsew')
        ttk.Label(self.waitFr, text='Wait...\nCreating plots...').grid()
        self.centrify_widget(self.loop_win)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.update()
gui = MyApp(root)
gui.mainloop()
```

External `loop_file`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def run_fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return run_fib(n-1) + run_fib(n-2)

def do_looping(queue):
    answer = run_fib(35)
    queue.put(answer)
```

If you run this small demo, you'll see a `Click me!` button. If you click it a pop-up window `Wait... Creating plots...` will appear and a separate thread will be run. Once the thread is finished the window is updated but **not resized**.

[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I resize the window after the update?

Comment: please show a complete example. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to avoid it, because of the size. Also I thought it could be some trivial function I forgot all about.

Comment: I didn't ask for your complete program. I asked for a complete example. You can probably write a program in a dozen or so lines of code that reproduces this issue. While this helps us, it helps _you_ more. Often, the effort you use to make the small example will make the solution to the problem more self-evident.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have modified my question with a working example. This is a small version of the current implementation.

Comment: I don't quite understand the "not resized" part of the problem.It appears to me that it is resized a tiny bit. If I hard-code `newsize` to be something really large, it resizes as I would expect. Is the problem you're asking about why the new size is computed incorrectly? You're not putting inside the frame that is inside the toplevel, so I don't expect it to change size.

Comment: Well, you see that white background around `9227465`? This is how I understand **not resized** after the calculation has been finished in a separate thread.
What I want is that when the separate thread completes, the `Wait... Creating plots...` window gets reduced enough to contain `9227465`.

Comment: Oh, you're expecting it to _shrink_?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Shrink ~ resize and become small enough to contain a new Label or whatever I put inside. Thing is, in this example we have a Label which is `9227465`. In my original window I am inserting plots which are much bigger than `Wait... Creating plots...` window. So, the plots get inserted but the window stays the same and you see nothing but a tiny fracture of the plot.

Comment: Well, now that I am thinking I could just destroy the `Toplevel` window and create a new one and insert the plot so it receives the correct new size...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're wanting the popup window to shrink to fit the new contents.

If that's the case, you don't have to do anything except *remove* the size constraint you had previously put on the window. When you call `geometry` with an argument, this will override any natural re-sizing that might otherwise happen in that window. You asked it to be a specific size, so tkinter tries hard to honor that wish.

If you pass an empty string to `geometry`, tkinter will remove that constraint and let the window grow or shrink to fit its contents.

Try this:

```
def finish_loop_window(self):
    # remove "Wait" message
    self.waitFr.destroy()

    # remove the fixed size of the window that was previously applied
    self.loop_win.geometry("")

    # create Frames for Toplevel window
    graphFr = ttk.Frame(self.loop_win, borderwidth=2, relief='groove')
    graphFr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    ttk.Label(self.loop_win, text=self.fib_result).grid()
```